# Reason behind colour of hibiscus and sunflower

Tags: plant-anatomy

What is the reason for the red colour of hibiscus and the yellow colour of sunflower?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Flower color is result of reflection of light due to various color pigments. Evolutionary such pigments were selected due to various reasons like to attract pollinators ([Dyer et al 2012](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rspb.2012.0827)). There are [two](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/bring-science-home-flower-pigment/) major types of flowers pigments

1. Carotenoids (produces yellow, orange and red colors)
2. Flavonoids (produces red, purple, magenta and blue colors)

However, flower color is affected by various other factors (e.g. other pigments, metal ions and its chemistry etc.) along with above pigments.

Hibiscus' dark red color is outcome of Anthocyanins which is water soluble flavonid ([Grajeda-Iglesias C et al 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27312226)). However, this pigment is highly unstable and depending on pH of the surrounding it can be red, purple, blue or black. (More details in [this](https://www.elsevier.com/books/anthocyanins-as-food-colors/markakis/978-0-12-472550-8) book). Hibiscus contains majorly delphinidin-3-O-sambubioside (Dp-samb) and cyanidin-3-O-sambubioside (Cy-samb) as the major anthocyanins ([DU and Francis 1973](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1365-2621.1973.tb02081.x)). Chemical reaction responsible for generation and utilisation of these pigment is shown below (borrowed from [Grajeda-Iglesias C et al 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27312226))

[image]

In above image, at low pH values $AH^+$ produces red color while  and $(A)$ produces purple/blue, which is thermodynamically unstable. In addition to that co-pigments like Hydroxylatedbenzoic and cinnamic acids, hydroxyflavones (which all are colorless) are also responsible for not only stabilizing these chemical products but enhances the color ([Grajeda-Iglesias C et al 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27312226)).